# Rollback Samsung Galaxy S7 camera app to the one in Android 6?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s7

When my Galaxy S7 updated to Android 7, the built-in camera app also got updated to a newer version. I preferred the previous one, mostly because I could easily change the picture ratio/resolution without having to dig into option menus.

Is there a way to install the previous version, either as a replacement, or side by side, of the new one?